# keyboard shortcut Ctrl + A doesn't work for selecting all elements of Select element in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-edge

I've this simple web page showing multi-select list box using HTML select element:

```html
<html>
  <head>    
  </head>

<body>

  <select multiple="multiple">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is what I'm doing:

1. Load this page into Google Chrome browser.
2. Click the select control by mouse so that one of its item gets selected and the element gets focus.
3. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> key combination.
4. All the four elements in the select box get selected as shown below:

   [image]

Behavior in Internet Explorer(IE) and Edge isn't the same which is depicted below. It selects the entire area where the HTML element is drawn on the DOM but doesn't selects the items of the element:

[image]

Is there any other keyboard shortcut for IE or it is really a limitation in behavior? Can someone shed some light on this.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but sounds like a design choice on Microsoft's end. If there's an alternative key combination it's probably worthless because users don't know it. There *might* be a way to grab the Ctrl+A press and implement a custom event handler - or you could add a "select all" button, possibly the easiest way to go

Comment: Initially I had also thought exactly the same to have a "select all" check box beside the select control but when I saw that `Ctrl+A` keyboard combination working (on chrome) then I thought of avoiding an extra control on the UI of my web page. I discovered it really late that the same doesn't work on MS browsers and I'm in a soup now.

Comment: Maybe show the button only to Microsoft browser users?